# Flutter Remove bottom underline from DropDropdownButton

Tags: flutter

I have a drop down menu that is positioned in my app bar. However it seems to have default with an underline. The flutter docs say that is defaults to 0.0 which cant be the case and I can see the underline. How do I remove this underline.

```
return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
  ),
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.30,
  child: Center(
    child: DropdownButton(
      items: _dropdownValues.map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(value), value: value)).toList(),
        onChanged: (String value) {
          setState(() {
            _currentlySelected = value;
          });
        },
      isExpanded: false,
      value: _currentlySelected,
    )
  )
);
```

**Design:**

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I manage to find the answer. Flutter has `DropdownButtonHideUnderline` which was super helpful. I just wrapped `DropdownButton` in the `DropdownButtonHideUnderline`.

**Code:**

```
return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.30,
    child: Center(
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton(
                items: _dropdownValues.map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(value), value: value)).toList(),
                onChanged: (String value) {
                setState(() {
                    _currentlySelected = value;
                });
                },
                isExpanded: false,
                value: _currentlySelected,
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: underline: container color not working in my case how to change drop-down button underline color in futter

Comment: @s.j you will have to mention either height or width of the container and it would work.

`underline: Container(color:Colors.red, height: 2.0)`

Answer (score 9):

Another alternative is to use the underline constructor of `DropdownButton` and set the color to transparent.

```
underline: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
```

In your case:

```
child: DropdownButton(
    items: _dropdownValues.map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(value), value: value)).toList(),
    onChanged: (String value) {
    setState(() {
        _currentlySelected = value;
    });
    },
    isExpanded: false,
    underline: Container(color: Colors.transparent),
    value: _currentlySelected,
)
```

Comment: Even simpler: underline: Container(),

Answer (score 3):

Another option is :

```
 underline: SizedBox(),
```